# the Zabbix server can not connect to clients

Tags: linux, python, zabbix

I have zabbix server on my centos7 and I want to monitor my Apache server running on my virtual machine with zabbix.

I'm using zabbixApacheUpdater.py python script and zabbix sender to send data to zabbix server. but every single time I run command:

```
[/opt/ZabbixApacheUpdater.py -z 192.168.1.200 -o 192.168.1.207 -l http://192.168.1.207/server-status?auto]
```

I get this error:

```
zabbix_sender [4318]: DEBUG: answer [{"response":"success","info":"processed: 0; failed: 20; total: 20; seconds spent: 0.000705"}]
Response from "192.168.1.200:10051": "processed: 0; failed: 20; total: 20; seconds spent: 0.000705"
sent: 20; skipped: 0; total: 20
Usage: ApacheStatsForZabbix [-z <Zabbix hostname or IP>] [-o <Apache hostname or IP>]
```

What did I do wrong ? is it related to the script?

Answer (score 0):

We need more information about the python script, meanwhile i am suspecting that you will need to create item / trigger with a specific name and call it in your script within zabbix_sender command in order to get catched on the server side.